# "GetVersionedSdkPath: Unexpected layout" error trying to build U-SQL project

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Two different computers, Windows 10 1803, brand new installs of VS2017 with v2.4.2000.0 of Azure Data Lake and Stream Tools. I try to build my ultra basic U-SQL project to run local and I get the following error...

> GetVersionedSdkPath: unexpected layout of SCOPE CPP SDK. This is
>   usually because the version found is out of date or empty. Often, this
>   problem is because scope studio will set the environment variable
>   SCOPE_CPP_SDK to the version included with it, and it will have the
>   wrong layout if the cpp sdk has been upgraded since scope studio was
>   installed. Closing the visual studio session will un-set this variable
>   and may solve the problem. Otherwise, make sure the Cpp Sdk you're
>   using is up to date.

I'm not sure what CPP SDK is... C++ SDK? Needless to say, no magical fix is happening by restarting Visual Studio.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Gave up on getting v2.4.2000.0 of Azure Data Lake and Stream Tools to work and ended up rolling back to v2.3.3000.2 which resulted in this problem...

E_CSC_SYSTEM_INTERNAL: Internal error! The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter.

Which I managed to fix by clearing the contents of the C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\USQLDataRoot folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue for the u-sql local run feature in Visual Studio 2017. Unfortunately there is no way to fix that in the tools. You can choose from either of the following solutions to resolve this issue.

1. Install Visual Studio 2019 and Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics tools extension
2. Download the package from https://aka.ms/usqlvc15. Unzip and copy it to your Visual Studio 2017 ScopeSDK folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC". Then restart Visual Studio. Check the screenshot here: [Visual Studio ScopeSDK path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGcMg.png)